# To know who has locked object

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans

I have 2 methods in class object that might be called from different threads and one method - timer event. I marked all 3 methods `synchronized`. But now I got situation when something has locked `this` (I suppose synchronized places lock on current object) and one of `synchronized` procedures cant proceed. How to know which method has locked `this`? I'm using `NetBeans` and `Java 1.4 JDK`.

Call stack looks inactive:

[image]

Comment: if you want to break the synchronization in to smaller parts give each method its own lock so when a method is locked it wont lock all the other methods

Comment: I expect that all 3 methods sooner or later will finish and will allow to proceed next synchronized methods and I happy with this performance. I can't figure out why one of these methods not finished. At least I need to know which method locks everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jconsole utility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) to see which thread blocks anothers.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have a built-in Way to know the exact thread blocking your synchronized code.

But I do not see any benefit from knowing the blocking thread.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using synchronized method, use a synchronized block and pass this, like below. And you get to know which method has locked it.
Also, I suggest to use Lock interface from java Concurrency if your jre is more than 1.5 else follow the below mentioned approach. Happy coding :)

```
method1() {
sysout("method1, going to lock");
synchronized(this) 
{
....
....
}
sysout("method1, going to unlock");
}


method2() {
sysout("method2, going to lock");
synchronized(this)
{
....
...
}
sysout("method2, going to un lock");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a thread dump to get thread states and lock statuses at any moment.

To take dump on Unix/Linux, use `kill -3 <pid>`

Quick reference to understand thread dumps: [Using Thread Dumps](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/using_threaddumps.html)